# Was Hemingway schizophrenic?

Tags: ernest-hemingway

Surrounding the death of Ernest Hemingway, there are declarations that he suffered vigilance from the FBI. It is also said that he believed badly that he was being checked at every turn by goverment security offices. He also received electroconvulsive therapy.

What I cannot find information on is if he suffered from a mental illness (which it appeared the case to be). Does anyone know which one was? Perhaps some kind of schizophrenia?